# Add marker to google maps, codes not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am building a website via bootstrap, and would like to include google maps with a marker on a specific adress. I have spend a long time designing and choosing colors for the map, but now it seems impossible for me, to add the marker. I have tried so many options from searching google. Here is my code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var styles = [
{
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'geometry.fill',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#bcd1d5' }
    ]
},{
    featureType: 'poi',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#2e1e0e' }
]
},{
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#d3cabd' }
    ]
},{
    featureType: 'road.local',
    elementType: 'all',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#d3cabd' }
    ]
},{
    featureType: 'landscape',
    elementType: 'all',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#f3e7d9' }
    ]
},

];

var options = {
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: ['Styled']
},
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.68453, 12.56812),
    zoom: 15,
    disableDefaultUI: true, 
    mapTypeId: 'Styled'
};
var div = document.getElementById('map');
var map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });
map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
};
```

Can anyone tell me what I have to do to get a working marker or anything I have to change/correct? 
THANKS!

Comment: try to create a example of your code.... it would help more to fix your issue... or add the whole code so it is easy to debug your issue... because you haven't shown your styling code...

Comment: How do you suggest I create an example? The thing is: Im am kind of lost at the moment... Would you like to see the entire code for my site or....?

Comment: edit your question there is a option to include HTML/CSS and javascript... paste your code so that i can work over it... i don't need the whole code... just enough to answer this question

Comment: There you go, I hope this is the code you need :)

Comment: Check out my answer below. run the code snippet and see your required output. :)

Comment: I don't see any code in your question that would display a marker.  How did you try to display one?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: "Styled Map" });
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: zoomType,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, long),
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
        map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

Use for loop around `var marker` to get dynamic marker..
Use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers
for more information

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var styles = [
{
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'geometry.fill',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#bcd1d5' }
    ]
},{
    featureType: 'poi',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#2e1e0e' }
]
},{
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#d3cabd' }
    ]
},{
    featureType: 'road.local',
    elementType: 'all',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#d3cabd' }
    ]
},{
    featureType: 'landscape',
    elementType: 'all',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#f3e7d9' }
    ]
}

];
        function loadMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                      mapTypeIds: ['Styled']
                },
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.68453, 12.56812),
                zoom : 16,
                disableDefaultUI: true, 
                mapTypeId: 'Styled'
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps-area"), mapOptions);
            var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });
            map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(55.68453, 12.56812),
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", loadMap);
    </script>
</body>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Maps</div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="maps-area" style="height: 500px;" onLoad="loadMap()"></div>
</div>
</html>
```